# ¿Cómo cambiar el contenido de un JPanel con el de otro JPanel?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, intellij-idea, interface, interfaz

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Java y actualmente genero 2 gráficas que pretendo incluir en mi JFrame, que sería mi Interfaz. A modo de prueba, ya tengo un JPanel inicializado donde deseo poner la gráfica. Para ello, obtengo un charPanel que agrego a un JPanel tal que así:

```
ChartPanel chart = ///....// no es importante, pero obtengo el objeto
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(chart);
```

Si el JPanel donde deseo poner el contenido de panel se llama Panel_Final, he intentado:

```
Panel_Final = panel;
////
Panel_Final.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
Panel_Final.removeAll();
Panel_Final.add(panel);
Panel_Final.repaint();
Panel_Final.revalidate();

///
```

¿Cómo puedo lograr mi objetivo de poder reproducir en ese panel el contenido del otro, de tal manera que cuando ejecute la interfaz, se muestre la gráfica?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien esto que haces... primero asignas `panel` a `Panel_Final` -> `Panel_Final = panel;` y luego intentas que se añada a si mismo? -> `Panel_Final.add(panel);` No creo que eso tenga mucho sentido, pues tanto `panel` como `Panel_Final` son el mismo objeto. Podrías por favor indicar cual es exactamente el error que tienes?? Porque explicas lo que quieres, pero no qué problema hay con tu código actual, con lo cual estoy aquí *intentando adivinar* y sería más fácil que me lo dijeses directamente... tal como se indica que hagas en [ask]!

Comment: Disculpa, no especifiqué bien que en el segundo bloque son dos formas con las que he intentado asignar el contenido a Panel_Final (dividido po ////). Entiendo que la segunda opción es mejor, pero no sé exactamente como lograrlo. No da un error como tal, sino que simplemente no se muestra nada.